# How to perform functional testing of a dynamic website?

Tags: web-applications, web, automated-tests

I have already test Firefox extension like "[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/)" and "[Molybdenum](http://www.molyb.org/confluence/display/molyb/Home)" but they are not really usefull with a dynamic website.

Indeed, the content changes often so all functionnal tests recorded are quickly deprecated.

Comment: Record and replay is a myth. Test automation needs to be treated with sound software development practices, so that your tests do not become quickly deprecated and you minimize the maintenance needed when things change. The Selenium IDE is just a starting point, allowing you to record the object interactions with the website, but any tests you record there should be ported to Selenium-RC and tweaked to be more robust and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Selenium-RC](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html)?

> Selenium-RC uses the full power of programming languages to create more complex tests like reading and writing files, querying a database ... condition statements, iteration ...

... and maybe you could use something like Rails' functional testing stuff. (Unfortunately I'm not allowed to provide you with a link.)

Answer (score 0):

Try [TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/) for a dynamic website. It supports changing content very well. It isn't a record/playback mechanism, but the syntax of the test language is very simple.

Just ask if you have any questions on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I also go with kschaper.Selenium RC has all the functionalities to test a dynamic website.